# Cypress cucumber tags not working in windows 10

Tags: tags, cucumber, cypress, bdd, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Following cypress command works in Mac :-

npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@TC1'
npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@TV1 or @TC2'

But for windows 10, the above does not work. I have to remove quotes in order to get it working.
npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS=@TC1

But now after removing quotes I won’t be able to pass multiple tags. I have tried all following ways but so far nothing has worked for multiple tags in windows 10.

Resolutions tried for windows 10 :-

npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='"@TC1 or @TC2"' // Not working in windows 10

npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS=^'"@TC1 or @TC2"' // Not working in windows 10

npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS=^'"”@TV1 or @TC2"”' // Not working in windows 10

npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='"@TC1 or @TC2"' // Not working in windows 10

Let me know if anyone has some way to get it working

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the built in [tagging capability of the cypress-cucumber-preprocessor](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor#running-tagged-tests) and this works fine for me with this call on windows cmd

```
yarn cypress run -e TAGS="@smoke or @final"
```

I'm using yarn in my case. But it should be the same with npx.